# C++ inputting from a file

Tags: c++, input, file-io

I have to do a program on girl scout cookies that inputs a .txt file that has a customer first name, number of boxes bought, and name of cookie. Price of box is $3.50. In the program i have to display the customer name, boxes sold, name of cookie, and amount due. And at the end, display number of customers, total boxes sold, and total amount due. This is what I have so far and im not sure why it doesnt run,or at least say file not found, and i have already made the .txt file its in my project folder, Any help is appreciated thanks!
      The error i get is "unable to start program...system cannot find file specified". I am pretty sure my file is in the right place

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    //Declare Variables

    string firstName;
    string cookieName;

    int boxesSold;
    int numCustomers;
    double amountDue;
    int totalCustomers;
    int totalBoxesSold = 0;
    double totalAmount = 0;

    inFile.open("girlscout.txt");
    if (inFile)
    {
        cout << "Customer     Boxes     Cookie Name" << endl;
        cout << "Name                              " << endl;

        while(!inFile.eof())//Not end of file
        {
            inFile >> firstName;
            inFile >> boxesSold;
            inFile >> cookieName;

            totalBoxesSold += boxesSold;
            totalAmount = boxesSold * 3.50;

            cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint;
            cout << setw(2) << firstName
            << right << setw(7) << boxesSold
            << cookieName << endl;
        }

        cout << "Total Boxes Sold: " << totalBoxesSold;
        cout << "Total Amount: " << totalAmount;
        inFile.close();
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Could not open file " << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: More info! What file isn't found? What's the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that file girlscout.txt isn't in the directory you need it to be for your program to find it.  you can fix this by putting the full path in your inFile.open call, or compiling and running the executable with your girlscout.txt file in the same directory

Comment: How do i do this? The .txt file is in the correct place i believe. The error i get is "unable to start program...system cannot find file specified"

Comment: @user1807815 See my answer, it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct (although it lacks all errors handling). Check that your file is in the working directory when you run your application. To see if it's just a problem with finding the file, try putting the full path to your file and see if it changes anything.

Otherwise, check that you have reading rights on your file. If it still doesn't work, you'll have to check for `in` state and see why it failed. Depending on your OS, you could investigate the situation with OS-specific functions (ReadFile on Windows, to see error code when you try to open the file). When you find the root cause and fix it, you can go back to the ifstream code.

And I guess you mean:

```
totalAmount += boxesSold * 3.50;
```

Comment: Im pretty sure the .txt file is in the correct place. The error i get is "unable to start program...system cannot find file specified". I dont know if this is an error before it gets to the file part or what.

Comment: it looks like an error even before your program actually runs. Try putting a `std::cout << "Hello World";` at the beginning of your `main` function to see if it ever gets run. Otherwise it's a system-wise issue.

Comment: I did that and it never begins to run. The error comes up right after i click debug

Comment: Ok, then it's most certainly a configuration issue with your IDE. It is not a C++ question per say.

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling and running on Visual Studio? I think your error just means that the *.exe file is moved automatically somewhere else - and when hitting "Run" it doesn't find the executable itself.

Comment: Yes im using visual studio, so how do i fix that?

Comment: First of all find the *.exe itself in your program directory, it might be in/moved to the folder "bin" or "Release" "Debug", ... or even in the root of your programs directory. After you know the real location - go to Visual Studio > Your Project > Right Click > Properties > Configuration Properties > General > "Output Directory"